# Can two branches point to the same commit?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I'd like to keep my `gh-pages` in sync with `master` on my github repo, and currently I am doing this with a script that generates an extra merge commit each time and in truth I only need a single commit.

It's true that I could simply neglect to update `master` and just use gh-pages for development, but I wanted to know if git supports the possibility where two local branches can point at the same commit.

There is a point to having both move forward. The repo exposed to the world at github.com tracks `master` while the Github Pages page at my_username.github.com (which hosts the live code samples & test pages that I actually use for testing) tracks `gh-pages`. Both should synchronize the important stuff (js code) and my question is about if it is possible for both to point to the same exact commit. Ignoring, for the moment, that this would mean that `master` would receive the extra files for the Pages site that don't really belong there. Still I don't mind having that transparency anyway, so it is simple for folks to figure out how the site is set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, two branches can point to the same commits. However in the case of `gh-pages` the branches don't share the same history, so you have to tell Git it's okay to basically `squash` the existing `gh-pages` branch.

This will point your gh-pages branch to whatever your local master is pointed to:

```
git push origin +master:gh-pages
```

Keep in mind, it will *squash* whatever `gh-pages` used to point to on the server. The `+` sign tells Git it's okay to squish stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I gleaned this from [your repo](http://github.com/unphased/ply).

```
$ git diff --stat master..gh-pages
 debug.js                     |    2 +-
 images/body-bg.png           |  Bin 0 -> 8859 bytes
 images/highlight-bg.jpg      |  Bin 0 -> 34222 bytes
 images/hr.png                |  Bin 0 -> 1037 bytes
 images/octocat-icon.png      |  Bin 0 -> 1651 bytes
 images/tar-gz-icon.png       |  Bin 0 -> 1671 bytes
 images/zip-icon.png          |  Bin 0 -> 1661 bytes
 index.html                   |   71 ++++++++
 javascripts/main.js          |    1 +
 params.json                  |    1 +
 stylesheets/print.css        |  226 +++++++++++++++++++++++++
 stylesheets/pygment_trac.css |   69 ++++++++
 stylesheets/stylesheet.css   |  371 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 13 files changed, 740 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

From the look of things the branches are basically the same with the addition of
some files/folders on `gh-pages`. The simple answer would be to kill `master`,
as [I have done](http://github.com/svnpenn/bm).

I would like to add that two types of "GitHub pages" exist.

- You have "user" pages, which would be akin to `svnpenn.github.io`
- You have "project" pages, which would be akin to `svnpenn.github.io/bm`

---

- User pages rely on the `master` branch to generate/display a page.
- Project pages rely on `gh-pages` branch to generate/display a page.

Let it be clear that a `gh-pages` branch has **no purpose** on a "user" repo,
much as a `master` branch has **no purpose** on a "project" repo, other than a
purpose you come up with.